# Calculate HMAC for WBXML document with user pin

Tags: c#, hmac, wbxml

I have created a WBXML document from my SyncML ota configuration XML document. To send this configuration to cellphone I need to encode this document with user-pin which is by default always taken as "1234"

This requires me to calculate HMAC of the WBXML document with the pin "1234". I'm stuck at this and would appreciate any help on this.

I've googled enough but nothing seems to help straight as I need, may be some code might help me.

Answer (score 0):

- [C# code for HMAC SHA1 Ecoding for userPIN security of OMA Client Provisoning](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showpost.php?s=0fbf1b467df4709829fef29580d12f89&p=239648&postcount=10)
  ([full thread](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?p=239648#post239648))

Does this help?